# Serverless querying NodeJS MSSQL and cannot get result back to callback

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, serverless

I'm writing a small Serverless function to query a MSSQL db using the node mssql library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#callbacks)

I've read the documentation and I think I'm doing everything right but getting confused - I can see the result in my logs, but the main function callback is not being called and therefore data not being outputted by the API (basically the whole thing times out)

Heres my Lambda function:

```
import {success, error} from './libs/response-lib';
import {EPDBConfig} from "./libs/Database-lib";
import sql from "mssql";
import config from "./config";

export function main(event, context, callback) {

    console.log("start");

    EPDBConfig().then(dbConfig => {

        if(config.debug) console.log("Hello!");

        let EPDBconfig = {
            user: dbConfig.dbuser,
            password: dbConfig.dbpassword,
            server: dbConfig.dbhost,
            database: dbConfig.dbname
        };

        sql.connect(EPDBconfig)
            .then(pool => {
                return pool.request()
                    .input('student_no', sql.Int, 129546)
                    .query('select * from Student where StudentNo = @student_no')
            }).then(result => {
                console.log("success!");
                if(config.debug) console.log('result', result);
                return result;
            }).catch(err => {
                if(config.debug) console.log('err1', err);
                return err;
            });

        sql.on('error', err => {
            if(config.debug) console.log('err2', err);
            return callback(null, error(err));
        });

        sql.on('done', result => {
            if(config.debug) console.log('done', result);
            return callback(null, success(result));
        });

    }).catch(err => {
        if(config.debug) console.log('err3', err);
        return callback(null, error(err));
    })
}
```

DB Config is pulled from AWS KMS for secure vars

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";
import config from "../config";

const kms = new AWS.KMS({
    region: AWS.config.region
});

export function EPDBConfig() {
    //DECRYPT THE DATABASE CONNECTION DETAILS

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let params = {
            CiphertextBlob: Buffer(process.env.epdb, 'base64')
        };
        kms.decrypt(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } // an error occurred
            else {
                let dbParams = JSON.parse(String(data.Plaintext));
                resolve(dbParams);
            }

        });
    });
}
```

and response lib:

```
export function success(data, message) {
    return buildResponse(200, true, data, message);
}
export function error(data, message) {
    return buildResponse(400, false, data, message);
}
export function unauthorized(data, message) {
    return buildResponse(401, false, data, message);
}
export function forbidden(data, message) {
    return buildResponse(403, false, data, message);
}
export function exception(data, message) {
    return buildResponse(500, false, data, message);
}

function buildResponse(statusCode, successState, data, message) {
    var body = {
        success: successState,
        message: message
    };

    if (successState) {
        body.data = data;
    }
    return {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    };
}
```

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong here? I think I have a whole pile of promises going on. The sql.on('done', result => { ... doesn't appear to work, and I tried adding 'return callback(null, success(result));' in the area where I have 'success'

Please help me!

Comment: What error do you see in CloudWatch?

Comment: Also, do you have a build process for that code that transpiles it to Node v6.10 compatible-code? That code won't work on Lambda as it is.

Comment: I ended up fixing the issue. Problem was that I wasnt terminating the mssql connection. So it would time out. I ended refactoring the connection placing it within a Promise, resolving the reponse out.

Answer (score 0):

So, I endded up resolving this with a bit of refactoring:

```
import sql from "mssql";
import _ from "lodash";
import {success, error} from './libs/response-lib';
import {DB} from "./libs/Database-lib";
import {Student} from "./models/ep.student";

export function main(event, context, callback) {
    DB().then(pool => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            pool.connect(err => {
                if(err) reject(err);
                pool.request()
                    .input('StudentNo', sql.Int, 129546)
                    .execute('StoredProcedure')
                    .then(result => {
                        if(process.env.debug) console.log('result', result);
                        let student = new Student();
                        _.assign(student, result.recordset[0]);
                        resolve(student);
                        pool.close();
                    }).catch(err => {
                    reject(err);
                    pool.close();
                });

            });
        });
    }).then(result => {
        if(process.env.debug) console.log('result', result);
        callback(null, success(result));
    }).catch(err => {
        if(process.env.debug) console.log('err', err);
        callback(null, error(err));
    });
}
```

The first issue was that I wasn't terminating my connection - just a note that I switched to using a stored procedure as this was always going to be the case.
The second issue was that I wasn't really using promises correctly (i think) I wrapped up my connection in a promise and only when I had the response did I resolve or reject it.